# Searching in google

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have made a text field, where I can search a web or in Google. The problem is that I can't search more than one word on google: I can search Stackoverflow, but I can't search Stackoverflow questions, for example. Here's the code:

```
{

if ([textField.text hasPrefix:@"http"]){
    url=[NSURL URLWithString:[textField text]];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    }else{
        stringOne = @"http://www.google.com/search?q=";
        NSString *stringTwo = TextField.text;
        NSString *googleSearchString =[stringOne stringByAppendingString:stringTwo];
        NSURL *google =  [NSURL URLWithString:googleSearchString ];
        request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:google ];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string may not be encoded correctly. Maybe try:

```
NSString* newGoogleSearchString = 
          [googleSearchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I was looking for a solution for this problem, I have spent too much time searching it! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the URL in a browser, you'll see something like this:

```
http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Stackoverflow+questions&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8
```

the argument that is important is **&q=Stackoverflow+questions** , notice the '+' sign that stands for a space.

**So, if you want your code to work, you have to replace spaces with a '+' character.**